# JS: Replace string that contains varying values

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

**I have this challenge:**

I need to replace this string: `"[[OM:random-string-id]]"` with this one: `'<div id="random-string-id"></div>'`

Where OM is a component TYPE to replace, and random-string-id is an id. Both parts can be dynamic and I only need to replace components with a type: 'OM'.

```js
# pseudocode

var text = [[$A:$B]] # this can be: "[[OM:something]]", "[[AD:somethingelse]]"

if ($A == 'OM') {
  text = text.replace(<div id='$B'></div>)
}
```

Input: `[[OM:something]] => Output: "<div id='something'></div>"`
Input: `[[AD:somethingelse]] => Output: "[[AD:somethingelse]]"`

**How is the best way to handle it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the replacer function of in-built replace:

```js
let str = "[[OM:random-string-idadsad]]"

str = str.replace(/^\[\[([A-Z]+):(.*)\]\]$/i, function(match, group1, group2, offset, string) {
  if (!group1 || !group2) { //or check arguments.length, if less than 5 return..
    return;
  }
  if (group1.toUpperCase() === "OM") {
    return "<div id='" + group2 + "'></div>"
  } else {
    return string;
  }
})

console.log(str)
```

Comment: ... both the regx and the replacement logic are unnecessary complex for what the OP is looking for, if one follows exactly the provided information ... *"... I only need to replace components with a type: 'OM'."*

Comment: The proposed solution is expandable and modular. Your es6 code will probably run slower, since it includes the destructuring. And it is inflexible since you hard coded the "OM". Caseing will break it. Won't work in ie11. Shall I go on?

Comment: String replacement turns into virtue signaling. Stage is yours Peter, I'm out of this.

Answer (score 2):

about the regx ...

... `/^\[\[OM\:([^\]]+)\]\]$/` ...

- one firstly `trim`s each string ... then ...
- `/^ ... $/` ... from the beginning to the end of a string look for ...
- `\[\[OM\:`... two opening brackets followed by `OM` and a `:` ... then
- `([^\]]+)`... capture/remember any sequence of characters that are not `]` ...
- followed by ... `\]\]` two closing brackets.

```js
function replaceSomething(str) {
  return str.trim().replace(
    (/^\[\[OM\:([^\]]+)\]\]$/),
    ((...result) => `<div id="${ result[1] }"></div>`)
  );
}

const listOfInputValues = ['[[OM:something]]', '[[AD:somethingelse]]', '[[OM:something]]', '[[AD:somethingelse]]'];

const listOfOutputValues = listOfInputValues.map(replaceSomething);

console.log('listOfOutputValues : ', listOfOutputValues);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

After discussing it with Ibrahim Tanyalcin, iterating the above given approach into something more generic (thus more flexible), Ibrahim's chosen example boils down to something like that ...

```js
function createMarkupWithCapturedId(match, id) {
  return ['<div id="', id, '"></div>'].join('');
}
function transformTagByName(tagName, tag) {
  const regX = RegExp('^\\[\\[' + tagName + '\\:([^\\]]+)\\]\\]$');
  return tag.trim().replace(regX, createMarkupWithCapturedId);
}

console.log(`'[[OM:random-string-idadsad]]' => '${ transformTagByName('OM', '[[OM:random-string-idadsad]]') }'`);

console.log(`'[[AD:random-string-idadsad]]' => '${ transformTagByName('OM', '[[AD:random-string-idadsad]]') }'`);

console.log(`'[[OM:random-string-idadsad]]' => '${ transformTagByName('AD', '[[OM:random-string-idadsad]]') }'`);

console.log(`'[[AD:random-string-idadsad]]' => '${ transformTagByName('AD', '[[AD:random-string-idadsad]]') }'`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The name describes the type of error, and the value of .name can be : EvalError, RangeError, ReferenceError,  SyntaxError, TypeError , and URIError. You may decide to handle the error differently depending on the error type which is returned by the .name property.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I completely miss your point. Are you talking about the title of the question?

Your answer seem not to be about the problem I have. I described that I have a string as an input, and the transformed string as an output - there is no object, no properties etc. Just two strings.

Comment: It looks like you've posted this answer to a wrong post?